# how to ignore php function arguments

Tags: php

I have two php functions:

```
1. function banners($position){...
2. function banners($size){...
```

and want to join them in one single function:

```
function banners($position, $size){...
```

How can I call this function but ignoring some arguments, for example

```
banners('ignore me', 250);

banners('home', 'ignore me');
```

`ignore me` = `give me all positions/sizes`

Comment: not getting you, clear it more with some code, do you want to make a function in which the parameters may be optional ?

Comment: pass the value as null when you want to ignore the parameters and then handle using if condition. If one is null then flow is in a way else the other way.

Comment: `banners($arguments = 'all')` inside `if($arguments==='all')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@bonaca i hope you want to make a function like below one, so just assign a default value for the arguments, try below one:

```
<?php
function banners($position = 'ignore me', $size = 'ignore me'){
    if($position == 'ignore me'){
        // do what every you want here
    }
    else{
        // passed parameter code here
    }


    if($size == 'ignore me'){
        // do what every you want here
    }
    else{
        // passed parameter code here
    }
}
banners('ignore me', 250);
banners('home', 'ignore me');
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply add something to the 'required' argument, like null or an other default value. Something like this:

```
function banners($position = null, $size = null)
```

Now the argument from this function will be optional because this argument has a default value. You can also hard-code these arguments in your function. Like:

```
$position = ($position == null ? "Hard-coded position" : $position);
$size = ($position == null ? "Hard-coded size" : $size);
```

Comment: OP has only one function with two argument

Comment: And how to call this function ignorig `position` for example?

Comment: @bonaca you can hard-code it in your function. Like `$position = ($position == null ? "Hard-coded position" : $position);` Same for the size variable

Comment: Seems to me it's simpler to have two separate functions?

Comment: @bonaca problem is that you may have all optional parameter so you have to pass all parameter at list because if you pass only one argument then it will be an error

Comment: + BunkerBoy - this should be ordinary thing for a glorified language such as php. Anyway, thanks a lot. Result - I must keep two identical functions with different arguments.

Answer (score 0):

since PHP 8 you can use named arguments like so:

```php
function banners($position = null, $size = null) {...}

banners(size: 250); // position will remain null, equivalent to: banners(null, 250);
banners(position: "home"); // size will remain null, equivalent to: banners("home");
```

[PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-158) and  [further reading and examples on stitcher.io](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-named-arguments)